# Two person wooden peg board game?

Tags: identify-this-game

What is the name of this game?  Board is a one-piece solid oak plank (approximately 7-3/4 inch by 13-3/4 inch) with 247 holes in three areas.  Appears that each player begins with 39 black or white pegs parked in separate and opposite "home" areas (each home area is 13 by 3 rows).  Playing area consists of a central 13 by 13 grid of holes.  I presume that pegs are moved from home area to playing area in turns.  I have the game but no idea of the name or rules.  I understand that this game was a favorite in "Games Magazine" in the mid-1980s.  Well made board and wooden dowel pegs.  No box (not sure there ever was one) or instructions.  Does this ring a bell with anyone?

Comment: If the home areas are connected to the central area so as to form a single contiguous 13 by 19 grid, then this sounds like a straightforward variant of Halma. This would also explain why there are no instructions.

Comment: Hans Adler:  Possibly!  Thanks for your response.  The game that I have is strictly a two-person game with three distinct areas.  Each of the two "home" areas is 13 by 3 rows and separated from the "playing" area (13 by 13 rows) by about  a 1-1/4 inch space.  Rows and Columns  in each of the three areas are separated by exactly 1/2 inch.  Art

Comment: Could you please include a picture?

Answer (score 1):

It could be a travel variant on a Go board. If you're not familiar with [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)), it's an ancient game played by two players, usually played with white and black stones. While the standard size of a Go board is 19x19 lines, 13x13 is a common "beginner" variant.

The main objection to this theory is the number of stones: you usually have enough to cover the whole board between the two players, so I would have expected 84 black pegs and 85 white ones.

Comment: No, not if each player has their own home area on the board.

Comment: @Gendolkari I was thinking of that just as game piece storage, rather than a real "home".

Answer (score -1):

I think you might be talking about a game called cribbage.

Comment: Cribbage boards typically don't have 39 pegs parked in the home area.